# How do i use a json as a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

im making a discord bot and am making a swear filter,

```
const swears = require("./words.json");

const swearWords = [swears];
if (swearWords.some(word => message.content.includes(word))) {
message.reply("BRUH NO NAUGHTEE WURDS");
message.delete().catch(e => {});
}
```

My Json is a list of swear words,

```
{
"words": [
 "example",
 "example2",
 "example3"
]}
```

but when someone swears nothing happens, could someone help me?

Comment: If you log `console.log(swearWords)` or `console.log(Array.isArray(swearWords))` what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
const swears = require("./words.json");

const swearWords = swears.words;

if (swearWords.some(word => message.content.includes(word))) {
  message.reply("BRUH NO NAUGHTEE WURDS");
  message.delete().catch(e => {});
}
```

When you `require` a JSON file it's basically as if you copy-paste the JSON code in place of the `require(...)` call.

Comment: Thank you so much, ive been working on this for like 5 hours

Comment: If the answer helped you, go ahead and select it as the accepted answer.  It's a nice reward for the person who took the time to answer your question.